# ruby assert_equal undefined method 'downcase' for 0..13:Range

Tags: ruby, api, http

I have a module called token wrapper, in which there is a method `getToken`:

```
def Tokenwrapper.getToken
  uri = URI.parse("[URL REDACTED]/api/authenticate")
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request.basic_auth("email@domain.com", "pass")
  request.content_type = "application/json"
  request["Accept"] = "application/json" 
  req_options = {
    use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  }

  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
 end
 response
end
```

When I attempt to test it with the following assertion:

`assert_equal("#<Net::HTTPOK:",Tokenwrapper.getToken[0..13])`

I get this error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'downcase' for 0..13:Range`

I don't manually invoke the downcase method, and I don't see any reason that ruby should be doing so automatically. Why is this happening and how do I make my test run?

I'll be honest I don't know a lot about HTTP API responses and how this area of networking operates, so I'd appreciate any resources as well as answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The response object has a `[]` method that [provides access to a header from the response](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html#method-i-5B-5D). When you're trying to do `getToken[0..13]` this is the method that's actually being called.

This `[]` is expecting a call like `response['Content-Type']` and uses `downcase` on the value passed in in order to handle header names case insensitively.

If you want to check the first few characters from the string representation of the response you can convert the response to a string and compare it, like this:

```
assert_equal("#<Net::HTTPOK:",Tokenwrapper.getToken.to_s[0..13])
```

Alternatively, can you use an assertion on the HTTP status code, e.g.

```
assert_equal(200, Tokenwrapper.getToken.code)
```